# Fetch in React.js not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-deployment

I am trying to do a `fetch` request in react.js and I don't seem to be fetching anything. I feel as though it is a stupid mistake and I am not noticing it. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TimeSearch from './TimeSearch.jsx';
import CurrentTime from './CurrentTime.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: []
    };
  }

  handleFormSubmit(item) {
    var url = 'https://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city=' + item + '&country=US&method=2';

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          Fajir: json.Fajir,
          Sunrise: json.Sunrise,
          Dhuhr: json.Dhuhr
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Welcome to Prayer Times!</h1>
        <h6>Search for times in any city in the United States</h6>
        <TimeSearch
          handleFormSubmit={item => {
            this.handleFormSubmit(item);
          }}
        />
        <CurrentTime Fajir={this.state.Fajir} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

// Time Search Component

import React, {Component} from 'react';

class TimeSearch extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <form onSubmit={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)}>
          <input type="text" id="lookUp" placeholder="Search by City" ref="seachBox" />
          <button type="submit" id="searchButtons">
            {' '}
            Search{' '}
          </button>
        </form>{' '}
      </ul>
    );
  }
  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = this.refs.searchBox.value;
    this.props.handleFormSubmit(item);
  }
}

export default TimeSearch;

// Current Time Component

import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CurrentTime extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="time">
        <h1 id="fajir"> {this.props.Fajir} </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CurrentTime;
```

**Update**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJx9T.png

Nothing shows up when I log the which is confusing me and I tried making an API request using Postman windows application and it works 100% fine so I have no clue what is going on now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your fetch code looks ok, are any errors being thrown in the console? It might be your handler not being bound to the correct context. If you don't bind the function correctly, the `this.setState` will cause an error because `this` is not the correct context. You might want to bind it in the constructor, or even better, use an initializer like this:

```
handleFormSubmit = (item) => {
  const url = `https://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city=${item}&country=US&method=2`;

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
     return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      this.setState({
        Fajir: json.Fajir,
        Sunrise: json.Sunrise,
        Dhuhr: json.Dhuhr
      });
    });
}
```

One thing to do is check your browser's network developer tab and make sure the request is going through correctly.

### Update

Looks like it's working now, see the fetch code below:

```js
const item = 'Chicago';
    var url = 'https://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city=' + item + '&country=US&method=2';

fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json);
  });
```

Comment: Hey, so I did check the network tab and it seems like the fetch request is not in there, it is showing nothing in there. It means nothing is being fetched

Comment: @ZubairAmjad Seems to be working now, I think `https` might work cross domain, but `http` didn't

Comment: I am trying to log it  and for some reason it is not letting me log on my browser, and nothing is being logged in the browser

Comment: Turns it out when I created a react app it messed up somewhere did that and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

hey try this fiddle it is working just open the console it is logging out the response.
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/harish_soni/69z2wepo/94926/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
handleFormSubmit = (item) => {
  const url = 'https://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city='+item+'&country=US&method=2';
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
     return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      this.setState({
        Fajir: json.Fajir,
        Sunrise: json.Sunrise,
        Dhuhr: json.Dhuhr
      });
    });
}
  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.handleFormSubmit(2)}>Click Me</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch statement looks okay.

A shot in the dark:

When attaching the event handler on the form, make sure to bind the context:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
```

Or in the constructor

```
this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)
```

Show us more of the Component please...

Comment: Hey Philipp, I have updated my post! It will have the components!

Comment: It looks okay, the fetch does work from dev-tools. I noticed you need to handle the json differently: json.data.timings contains your desired properties.

Comment: Hey Phillipp, so it would be something like json.data.timings.Fajir right?